# How to add a conditional variable format to nginx log_format with setting escape=json?

Tags: logging, nginx-config

Can anyone with **nginx configuration** skills help me, please?

I have my nginx conf file and I want to change my log format so that if a value is not found, a hyphen would be logged.

Nginx logging [documentation][1] has this option documented, but only if the log_format is set to escape=default. I am currently using escape=json option and want to keep that. Right now the empty string is logged, if the value is not found. Can I modify the configuration somehow to have the hyphen as a default empty value?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by mapping the parameter as shown in

https://www.nginx.com/blog/avoiding-top-10-nginx-configuration-mistakes/#if

```
map $user_id $userId {
default "$user_id";
""      "-";
}
```